# How do I ensure the data has arrived before the template tries to render it?

Tags: angularjs, angular, redux, immutable.js, angular-cli

I made an app with angular-cli, Immutable and Redux. I followed instructions from [this](http://houssein.me/redux/immutablejs/angular2/2016/07/04/angular2-with-immutablejs-and-redux.html) article which does not describe how to get data. My app needs to initialize the Redux store with data from an asynchronous http call.

I have a component for listing the data which has a template. This component gets its data from the store which depends on a service which makes the http call. The http call works but the app throws an exception that indicates the listing component is trying to get the data before it has arrived.

My repository is [here](https://github.com/dancancro/bernierebuttals)

A demo of the app is [here](https://github.com/dancancro/bernierebuttals)

Error message:

```
main.js:21 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined
    at a.get [as objections] (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:18:22268)
    at a._View_a0.detectChangesInternal (a.template.js:189:37)
    at a.detectChanges (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13138)
    at a.detectViewChildrenChanges (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13774)
    at a._View_a_Host0.detectChangesInternal (a.template.js:34:8)
    at a.detectChanges (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13138)
    at a.detectContentChildrenChanges (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13588)
    at a.detectChangesInternal (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13345)
    at a.detectChanges (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13138)
    at a.detectViewChildrenChanges (https://dancancro.github.io/bernierebuttals/main.js:32:13774)
```

Here are some relevant parts of the code: (I'm working on this. The repository contains the current code)

list.component.html

```
...

<ul id="objection-list" [sortablejs]="store.objections" [sortablejsOptions]="options" (update)="setTouched()">
<li *ngFor="let objection of store.objections">
   <list-objection 
   [objection]="objection" 
   [editable]="editable"
   (onEdit)="setTouched()" 
   (onReordered)="setReordered(objection)"
   ></list-objection>
</li>
</ul>

...
```

list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { SortablejsOptions, SORTABLEJS_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular-sortablejs';
import Immutable = require('immutable');

import { ObjectionComponent } from './objection/objection.component';
import { ObjectionModel } from '../objection';
import { ObjectionStore } from '../objection-store';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { addObjection } from '../actions';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.component.css'],
  providers: [ObjectionStore, DataService],
  directives: [ObjectionComponent, SORTABLEJS_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  private sub: any;
  editable: boolean = false;
  touched: boolean = false;
  expanded: boolean = false;
  options: SortablejsOptions = {
    disabled: false
  };
  objectionID: number;

  constructor(
    private store: ObjectionStore,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ...

}
```

objection-store.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import Immutable = require('immutable');
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import { ObjectionAction } from './actions';
import { reducer } from './reducer';
import { ObjectionModel } from './objection';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectionStore {
  private sub: any;
  store: any;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService) {
           this.store = createStore(reducer, Immutable.List<ObjectionModel>(objections.json()));
    });

  }
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { ObjectionModel } from './objection';
import { Area } from './area';

let objectionsPromise;

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    result: Object;
    combined: any;
    error: Object;
    getUrl: string = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbymzGKzgGkVo4kepy9zKIyDlxbnLbp-ivCvj8mVMClmWgr-V-g/exec?json=1';
    postUrl: string = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbymzGKzgGkVo4kepy9zKIyDlxbnLbp-ivCvj8mVMClmWgr-V-g/exec';

    static getObjection(objections: any[], id: number): ObjectionModel {
        return objections.filter(function(objection) {
            return objection.id === id
        })[0];
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        objectionsPromise = this.http.get(this.getUrl).toPromise();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Answer**

To answer the immediate question, getting the objections from the server and putting them in a template can be simply done like this:

1. Use [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-class.html) to bind an observable directly into the template. Async pipe 'unboxes' observables (promises too) and updates your template when they change.

```html
<ul id="objection-list"
    [sortablejs]="store.objections"
    [sortablejsOptions]="options"
    (update)="setTouched()">
  <li *ngFor="let objection of objections | async">
    <list-objection 
                    [objection]="objection" 
                    [editable]="editable"
                    (onEdit)="setTouched()" 
                    (onReordered)="setReordered(objection)">
    </list-objection>
  </li>
</ul>
```

2. Use DataService to initialize this observable when your component is initialized:

```js
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.component.css'],
  providers: [ObjectionStore, DataService],
  directives: [ObjectionComponent, SORTABLEJS_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  // ...

  private objections: Observable<ObjectionModel[]>;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.objections = this.dataService.getObjections();
  }

  // ...
```

3. Fix up your data service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { ObjectionModel } from './objection';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    result: Object;
    combined: any;
    error: Object;
    getUrl: string = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbymzGKzgGkVo4kepy9zKIyDlxbnLbp-ivCvj8mVMClmWgr-V-g/exec?json=1';
    postUrl: string = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbymzGKzgGkVo4kepy9zKIyDlxbnLbp-ivCvj8mVMClmWgr-V-g/exec';

    getObjections(private http: Http): Observable<ObjectionModel[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.getUrl) // returns an observable of the response
            .map(response => response.json()); // transforms it into an observable of ObjectionModels
    }
}
```

**Notes on Redux**

Note that this has all been done without Redux.

In general, I like Redux and I use it a lot. However in your example you seem to be doing a couple of unorthodox things:

1. You are creating a store in your ObservableStore service - this suggests to me that you are planning on having several stores in your app. One of the main principles of Redux is global immutable state, meaning that there is normally only one Redux store in an application.
2. You seem to by trying to fetch the initial data set from the server and then creating your store when the response has come back. It's not generally a good idea to couple the store creation to an HTTP request like this.  Instead I recommend creating an empty store when you initialize your app, and then updating it via reducer when the HTTP request comes back.
3. You can do raw Redux in Angular 2, but you may find it a little frustrating getting it to work with Angular's observable-heavy APIs. Fortunately people (including me) have done this work for you in the form of Observable-oriented redux libraries like [ng2-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux) and [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store)

If you were to use ng2-redux, things would look more like this:

Top-level app component: build your store and initialize it:

```
import { NgRedux } from 'ng2-redux';
import { rootReducer } from './reducers';

@Component({ /* ... */ })
class App {
  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<any>) {
    this.ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, {});
  }
}
```

List component: bind your template to a selector from the store's current data.  Also trigger a data fetch on initialization.

```
import { NgRedux, select } from 'ng2-redux';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService],
  directives: [ObjectionComponent, SORTABLEJS_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  // ...

  // Magic selector from ng2-redux that makes an observable out
  // of the 'objections' property of your store.
  @select('objections') objections: Observable<ObjectionModel[]>;

  constructor(
      private ngRedux: NgRedux<any>,
      private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription = this.dataService.getObjections()
         .subscribe(objections => this.ngRedux.dispatch({
             type: FETCH_OBJECTIONS_OK,
             payload: objections
         },
         error => this.ngRedux.dispatch({
             type: FETCH_OBJECTIONS_ERROR,
             error: error
         });
      )
  }
}
```

OK... so how does the data actually get into the store? Via the reducer.  Remember in redux store state can *only be changed from a reducer*.

```
export function objectionReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_OBJECTIONS_OK: return [ ...action.payload ];
        case ADD_OBJECTION: return [ ...state, action.payload ];
        // etc.
    }

    return state;
}
```

We can also track errors in a reducer too if we want, how you want to structure this is up to you.

```
export function errorReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_OBJECTIONS_ERROR: return { objectionFetch: action.error }
    }
}
```

Since we have one store, we modularize the reducers instead and compose them together:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { objectionReducer } from './objection.reducer';
import { errorReducer } from './error.reducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    objections: objectionReducer,
    error: errorReducer
});
```

**More to Learn/Disclosure**

Disclosure: I am one of the authors of Ng2-Redux. However Ngrx/Store is also a great alternative for doing redux with Ng2, and while the implementation is different using it is very similar to what I have described above.

I and my colleagues also maintain a number of training resources on Angular2 and on Redux, which I will provide below:

- A good Angular2-specific intro to redux: http://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/redux/
- An intro to Observables: http://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/
- Ng2-Redux documentation: https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I wasn't planning to have several stores. I'm new to this and was just following the article's example. I can't tell whether the code from your Basic Answer part is to be used with the second part. If so, I don't see anything called "store" defined in the second part that is to be used in the template binding "store.objections". If not, I don't know what to do in the template. I'm also stuck on the dependency on ng2-redux. My app is generated by angular-cli and so uses System.js. I have pushed my changes to github.

Comment: I made a little progress today. The page is loading without any errors including the dependency one. The http call is still getting data. But it's not displaying the data bound to the template. I'm so close!!! Changes pushed to github.

Comment: Yeah the basic answer is how to do it without redux; the second answer is how to do it with.

Comment: In both cases the template is the same: `<li *ngFor="let objection of objections | async">`

`objections` is the member variable of the component class; it is the observable returned by HTTP (in the basic answer) or the observable selected out of the store in the Redux answer.

Because it's an observable, you have to use `| async` to hook it up to your template.

Answer (score 1):

Your data service is wrong. you are missing the point of the promise/observable.
you should read angular documentation about http client. at least read this part:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#promises

No http call in the constructor!
 this is more like it:

```
getHeroes (): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                  .toPromise()
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

After you get use to that, I really recommend you read some about Observables. much cleaner and advanced.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really want to learn a second best approach if there is a better one. I also learn best by exposure to complete assemblies rather than distinct concepts. I actually have read about Observables but unfortunately doing so just doesn't get into my head the exact way to use observables, immutablejs, redux and angular 2 together. Honestly, reading about any concept in isolation doesn't get me the ability to use technologies together. I moved the http call from the constructor to the onInit method and updated the repo but I have the same problem.

Comment: 1. i am not sure you can hook OnInit on Injectable class. 2. even if you could it's the same thing. you can't do this. you need to make the http request from the specific function and return the promise back to the caller.

Comment: Ok. I get the general spirit of what you're saying but unfortunately without seeing actual code, I can't solve this problem. I will plead with the article author to provide that. All real projects have async data fetching. So if he has used it in a real project then he has already done it.

Comment: There are plenty of async http example out there, they are all the same. service return an observable, caller subscribe the observable and on success you can be sure that the data is yours to work with. thats the pattern that is what you need to do. read this section, it will do you good: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#rxjs